# How to convert friend id's to corresponding name in twitter using twitter4j?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

Here I'm able to get all friends ids. But for the same I need to get name of corresponding id. How can I get it? For getting friends ids I'm using Twitter4j lib and my code is:

```
String friendsIds = twitter.getFriendsIDs(MyId, cursor).toString();
```

For this output is:

> friendsIds:IDsJSONImpl{ids=[43347766, 2369925598, 238933377, 243381784, 946613156, 541261639], previousCursor=0, nextCursor=0}

How can I get names for those ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`lookupUsers(long[])`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/UsersResources.html#lookupUsers%28long%5B%5D%29) to bulk retrieve your friends and get access to their screen names, e.g.:

```
final IDs friendIds = twitter.getFriendsIDs(MyId, cursor);
final ResponseList<User> users = twitter.lookupUsers(friendIds.getIDs());

for (User u : users) {
    System.out.println(u.getScreenName());
}
```

Note that you can retrieve up to a maximum of 100 users at a time using the `lookupUsers` API call, so you may have to split the ids up if you have more than 100 friends.

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan, How can i sort those names according to alphabetically,could you please help me?

Comment: No problem. Take a look at [this existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2784576/69875) - you can apply the same approach using `getScreenName()` instead of `getStartDate()`.