# How to sort Name of Screen in twitter?

Tags: java, sorting, twitter, twitter4j

Here i'm able to get User Screen names and printing with the below code,but how can i sort those name alphabatically.

```
Twitter twitter = (Twitter) request.getSession().getAttribute("twitter");
String name = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("name");
long cursor = -1;
IDs ids = twitter.getFollowersIDs(name, cursor);
do {
    for (long id : ids.getIDs()) {
        User user = twitter.showUser(id);
        out.println(user.getName());
    }
} while ((cursor = ids.getNextCursor()) != 0);
```

This is my code where i'm getting names,how can i sort names.Thank for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Comment: Sorry@Jonathan,I'm unable to get it,could you please tell me how to sort those names?

Comment: Apologies on reflection that question I highlighted may not be appropriate. I was still thinking about your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24135504/69875) where you had a `ResponseList<User>` to deal with!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually a `Comparator` may be more than you need, I got mixed up with your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24135504/69875).

You can simply collect the names themselves in a list and then sort, e.g.:

```
...
final List<String> names = new LinkedList<String>();
do {
    for (...) {
        ...
        names.add(user.getName());
    }
} while (...);

Collections.sort(names)
```

If you inspect `names`, it will now be sorted.